# DateTimeParseException: Text '1-Aug-2018' could not be parsed at index 2

Tags: java, datetimeformatter, datetimeparseexception

I need to process data in the form of a Tab-delimited file with dates in the form dd-MMM-yyyy, for example 1-Aug-2018 or 15-Sep-2023.  My code is:

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("d-MMM-uuuu");
private LocalDateTime toDate (String raw) {
       LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse (raw, DATE_FORMATTER);
    return date;
}
```

My exception is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1-Aug-2018' could not be parsed at index 2

Research done:

- Careful reading of Oracle Java documentation
- Tried `dd` instead of `d` but that just moved the index to 0 instead of 2
- Tried `yyyy` instead of `uuuu` (out of desperation, the problem clearly isn't there)
- An hour trawling the Internet but the few examples of my pattern *with* DateTimeFormatter (instead of SimpleDate, doesn't anybody ever clean up the old garbage on the Internet?!) are using it to format output rather than parsing input.
- Another hour trawling StackOverflow, which is even worse than the general Internet for obsolete solutions (although the answers are way more professional), but all the answers seem to involve different patterns to mine and I can't see any differences in the code

Any suggestions?  Or directions to relevant answers?

Comment: What is your system's locale? With other words, what does `Locale.getDefault()` return?

Comment: **Specify** English. `private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: Your input doesn't contain a time value, so using `LocalDateTime` is probably not a good place to start, I'd consider `LocalDate` instead, but as stated, this is likely a localisation issue

Comment: Definitely granted, this one isn’t easy to search for no matter that others have had the same problem before.

Comment: A useful trick when parsing fails: Try formatting the expected date-time using the same formatter, `LocalDateTime.of(2018, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0) .format(DATE_FORMATTER)`. Now you should see the month coming out in a different language and/or with a small `a` instead of the capital `A`, which might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: You probably don’t want a `LocalDateTime` at all. `LocalDate` should do fine. If I am wrong, you may get a `LocalDateTime` from `LocalDate.parse (raw, DATE_FORMATTER).atStartOfDay()` (after you have specified the right locale).

Comment: At [Java Playground](https://dev.java/playground/), paste: `import java.time.* ;
import java.time.format.* ;

LocalDate ld = 
  LocalDate.parse(
      "1-Aug-2018" , 
      DateTimeFormatter
       .ofPattern( "d-MMM-uuuu" )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
  );
System.out.println( ld ) ;`